# New Confluence wiki page event to custom Application

Tags: mule, mule-studio, anypoint-studio, mulesoft

We have a requirement to capture New wiki page creation event and call our REST APIs to create corresponding data in our application.

Since I am just getting started, could you please point me if there are any Confluence connectors I can use out of the box or any other way I can implement this with MuleSoft.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can search existing connectors in [Anypoint Exchange](https://www.mulesoft.com/exchange/). Currently there are none for Confluence.

You can use the [HTTP Requests](https://docs.mulesoft.com/connectors/http/http-request-ref) to call Confluence REST API.

Another alternative could to [write a RAML specification](https://docs.mulesoft.com/design-center/design-create-publish-api-raml-editor) for Confluence API and generate a [REST Connector](https://docs.mulesoft.com/exchange/to-deploy-using-rest-connect), though writing the full API in REST could require more effort.